# Email Failed To Sync

Tags: sync, email

I am using a Nexus 5, running 4.4.2 - not rooted. Sync'ing stopped working for my email. Below is what my log shows (I removed my email address). I use POP and Exchange and both are no longer working. I rebooted a few times, to no avail. Before I do anything more drastic, I'm wondering if anyone knows why this is occurring.

```
02-05 12:00:37.300 D/SyncManager(  754): failed sync operation <email_address_removed> u0 (com.google.android.pop3), com.google.android.email.provider, PERIODIC, latestRunTime 9040633, reason: Periodic, SyncResult: stats [ numIoExceptions: 1]
02-05 12:00:37.310 I/notification_cancel(  754): [android,-1971419177,NULL,0,0,0]
02-05 12:00:37.570 I/Email   ( 2225): ConversationListView hide sync status bar
02-05 12:00:37.780 I/force_gc( 2225): Binder
02-05 12:00:37.810 D/SyncManager(  754): failed sync operation <email_address> u0 (com.google.android.exchange), com.google.android.email.provider, USER, latestRunTime 9075555, EXPEDITED, reason: 10037, SyncResult: stats [ numParseExceptions: 1]
02-05 12:00:37.820 I/sync    (  754): [com.google.android.email.provider,1,3,13808728]
02-05 12:00:37.820 I/notification_cancel(  754): [android,-1235235863,NULL,0,0,0]
02-05 12:00:37.820 D/SyncManager(  754): not retrying sync operation because SYNC_EXTRAS_DO_NOT_RETRY was specified <email_address_removed> u0 (com.google.android.exchange), com.google.android.email.provider, USER, latestRunTime 9076485, EXPEDITED, reason: 10037
```

NOTE: Gmail is working fine.

Comment: NOTE: Gmail is working fine.

Comment: OK, so it's not a network issue. Unfortunately you're using POP, so clearing data from the email app would make you lose your mail. Try clearing cache at least, maybe that helps (`numParseExceptions` looks like something messed up; `numIoExceptions` even looks a little more drastic; could it be your storage is full?).

Comment: No, I have plenty of storage. But, I did clear Cache so let's see what happens.

Comment: Dang! Nothing is helping. Cleared cache, cleared data, readded the account and NOTHING! I can send but can't receive

Comment: Well, if we cannot solve the problem, we can look for alternatives: you could try another mail client. [K-9 mail](http://www.appbrain.com/app/k-9-mail/com.fsck.k9) might be a good choice (I use it for years already without any issues).

Comment: An email was corrupt (not sure how) and once it was deleted, exchange started working again. I discovered it when I started clearing my inbox in advance of my IT group rebuilding my email box. Strange! A few days later, it occurred again and sure enough, I cleaned out my inbox and it started working.